# Losing IO on return type

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble with the function consensus in this block of code. The recursive definition of consensus is returning **[Action]** instead of **IO [Action]**.

I am new to Haskell and do not understand why this is happening. I was under the impression that it was not possible remove the IO from a return value.

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (group, sort, maximumBy)

data Action = A | B deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

-- Sometimes returns a random action
semiRandomAction :: Bool -> Action -> IO (Action)
semiRandomAction True a = return a
semiRandomAction False _ = do
  x <- randomRIO (0, 1) :: IO Int
  return $ if x == 0 then A else B

-- Creates a sublist for each a_i in ls where sublist i does not contain a_i
oneOutSublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
oneOutSublists [] = []
oneOutSublists (x:xs) = xs : map (x : ) (oneOutSublists xs)

-- Returns the most common element in a list
mostCommon :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
mostCommon = head . maximumBy (comparing length) . group . sort

-- The function in question
consensus :: [Bool] -> [Action] -> IO [Action]
consensus [x] [action] = sequence [semiRandomAction x action]
consensus xs actions = do
  let xs' = oneOutSublists xs
      actions' = map (replicate $ length xs') actions
  replies <- mapM (uncurry $ consensus) (zip xs' actions')
  map mostCommon replies -- < The problem line

main = do
  let xs = [True, False, False]
      actions = [A, A, A]
  result <- consensus xs actions
  print result
```

ghc output

```
➜  ~ stack ghc example.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( example.hs, example.o )

example.hs:29:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO [Action]
        Actual type: [Action]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: map mostCommon replies
      In the expression:
        do let xs' = oneOutSublists xs
               actions' = map (replicate $ length xs') actions
           replies <- mapM (uncurry $ consensus) (zip xs' actions')
           map mostCommon replies
      In an equation for ‘consensus’:
          consensus xs actions
            = do let xs' = ...
                     ....
                 replies <- mapM (uncurry $ consensus) (zip xs' actions')
                 map mostCommon replies
   |
29 |   map mostCommon replies
   |
```

Comment: Does `mapM` solve it (instead of `map`)?

Comment: No, when changed to mapM, replies is expected to be [[IO Action]] but it is actually [[Action]]

Comment: I have tried shuffling things around for awhile, and I always seem to end up with at least one type error. I assume there is some pathological mistake in my code.

Comment: just do `return $ map mostCommon replies`

Comment: Side note: `return` is identical to `pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`, but with a more restrictive type signature (`Monad m => a -> m a`), so `pure` can be used in more contexts. Plus it’s slightly shorter, and I think its name better conveys its meaning: lift a pure value into a functor. `return x` doesn’t return `x`, it constructs an action that “returns” `x` (in some manner specific to the given monad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
return $ map mostCommon replies
```

`return` is a standard function that wraps values into monad.

You can think of it this way:

- you're inside an IO monad, so GHC expects that your function will return `IO a`
- you're returning `[] Action` (it's just another way of writing `[Action]`)

so there are two errors here:

- your actual return type does not match your type annotation (`[Action]` vs `IO [Action]`)
- the types wrapping the Action (`[]` and expected `IO`) do not match

When you use `return` function here you fix both errors.

Answer (score 5):

`consensus` is supposed to return a value of type `IO [Action]`. That's what `Expected type: IO [Action]` means.

However, `map mostCommon replies` is an expression of type `[Action]` (because `map` returns a plain list, no `IO`).

> I was under the impression that it was not possible remove the IO from a return value.

Indeed, which is why you're getting a type error. The "cannot remove IO" thing is not a fundamental property, it just follows from the types of available operations in the standard library.

So how do we solve this?

You have a value of type `IO [[Action]]`, namely `mapM (uncurry $ consensus) (zip xs' actions')`. You want to apply `mostCommon` to each inner list (within the outer list within `IO`).

By using `<-` in a `do` block, you can locally "extract" values from `IO a`:

```
replies <- mapM (uncurry $ consensus) (zip xs' actions')
-- replies :: [[Action]]
```

By using `map`, you can apply `mostCommon` to each sublist:

```
map mostCommon replies :: [Action]
```

What's missing is that you need to "rewrap" your value in `IO` to make the `do` block pass type-checking (each individual statement in a `do` block must have the same base type, in this case `IO`):

```
return (map mostCommon replies)
```

Here `return :: [Action] -> IO [Action]` (or in general: `return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a`).